# How to calculate bill by using input from user?

Tags: c

I have very confusing problem of calculating the bill for a computer shop based on the stuff that consumer buys. Things to choose from are as follows:

```
* The base package cost is $599 and includes 4 GB of memory,
  a 512Gb Hard Drive and a 21" LED monitor.
  Permitted upgrades to the base system add the following costs:
  + Upgrade to 8 GB or 12 GB of Memory adds $99 and $189 respectively.
  + Upgrade to 27" LED monitor adds $199.
  + Upgrade to a 128 GB SSD adds $119.
  + NO Video card upgrade possible for the base package.

* The professional package cost is $899 and includes 8 GB of memory,
  a 1TB Hard Drive and a 27" LED monitor.
  Permitted upgrades to the professional system add the following costs:
  + Upgrade to a maximum 16 GB of Memory adds $189.
  + Upgrade to 32" LED monitor adds $199.
  + Upgrade to a 256 or 512 GB SSD adds $189 and $399 respectively.
  + Upgrade to a discrete 2GB Video card adds $209.

* The game package cost is $1499 and includes 16 GB of memory,
  a 256 SSD Drive, a 32" LED monitor, and a discrete 2 GB Video card.
  Permitted upgrades to the game system add the following costs:
  + Upgrade to a maximum 32 GB of Memory adds $389
  + Upgrade to 28" 4K HD monitor adds $299
  + Upgrade to a 512 GB or 1 TB SSD adds $299 and $599 respectively.
  + Upgrade to a discrete 4GB Video card adds $399.
```

How do i calculate the overall bill if consumer makes certain modifications after buying any pc?

I've written the following program so far but it doesn't seems to be going fine with this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    int choice, addon1, addon2, addon3, addon4;
    float price, stot, bpack, ppack, gpack;


    printf("Welcome to the IPC Company's Computer System Calculator\n\n");
    printf("Enter the package desired\n");
    printf("(1: Basic, 2: Professional, 3: Game System) :");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if(choice == 1){

        printf("\nEnter additional memory required\n");
        printf("(o: 4 GB included, 1: 8 GB, 2: 12 GB) :");
        scanf("%d", &addon1);
        printf("\nEnter monitor required\n");
        printf("(0: 21 inch LED included, 1: 27inch LED) :");
        scanf("%d", &addon2);
        printf("\nEnter Hard Drive required\n");
        printf("(0: 512 GB already included, 1: 128 GB SSD) :");
        scanf("%d", &addon3);

        printf("\n================================\n");
        printf("Basic Package:      \t     599.00\n");
        if(addon1 == 0)
            printf("4 GB memory:        \t 0.00\n");
        if(addon1 == 1)
            printf("8 GB Memory:        \t 99.00\n");
        if(addon1 == 2)
            printf("12 GB Memory:       \t 189\n");
        if(addon2 == 0)
            printf("21 inch LED monitor:\t 0.00\n");
        if(addon2 == 1)
            printf("27 inch LED monitor:\t 199.00\n");
        if(addon3 == 0)
            printf("512 GB Hard Drive:  \t 0.00\n");
        if(addon3 == 1)
            printf("128 GB SSD:         \t 119.00\n");

        printf("================================\n");

        stot = ;
        printf("Sub Total: ", stot);


    }
    if(choice == 2){
        printf("\nEnter additional memory required\n");
        printf("(o: 8 GB included, 1: 16 GB) :");
        scanf("%d", &addon1);
        printf("\nEnter monitor required\n");
        printf("(0: 27 inch LED included, 1: 32 inch LED) :");
        scanf("%d", &addon2);
        printf("\nEnter Hard Drive required\n");
        printf("(0: 1TB Hard Drive, 1: 256 GB SSD, 2: 512 GB SSD) :");
        scanf("%d", &addon3);
        printf("\nEnter Video Card required\n");
        printf("(0: 2 GB video card) :");
        scanf("%d", &addon4);

        printf("\n================================\n");
        printf("Professional Package:      \t     899.00\n");
        if(addon1 == 0)
            printf("8 GB memory:        \t 0.00\n");
        if(addon1 == 1)
            printf("16 GB Memory:       \t 189.00\n");
        if(addon2 == 0)
            printf("27 inch LED monitor:\t 0.00\n");
        if(addon2 == 1)
            printf("32 inch LED monitor:\t 199.00\n");
        if(addon3 == 0)
            printf("1TB GB Hard Drive:  \t 0.00\n");
        if(addon3 == 1)
            printf("256 GB SSD:         \t 189.00\n");
        if(addon3 == 2)
            printf("512 GB SSD:         \t 399.00\n");
        if(addon4 = 0)
            printf("2 GB Discrete Video Card: \t 209.00");

        printf("================================\n");

    }
    if(choice == 3){
        printf("\nEnter additional memory required\n");
        printf("(o: 16 GB included, 1: 32 GB) :");
        scanf("%d", &addon1);
        printf("\nEnter monitor required\n");
        printf("(0: 32 inch LED included, 1: 28 inch 4K HD monitor) :");
        scanf("%d", &addon2);
        printf("\nEnter Hard Drive required\n");
        printf("(0: 256 GB already included, 1: 1 TB SSD) :");
        scanf("%d", &addon3);
        printf("\nEnter Video Card required\n");
        printf("(0: 2 GB video card included, 1: 4 GB video card) :");
        scanf("%d", &addon4);

        printf("\n================================\n");

        printf("Game Package:      \t     899.00\n");
        if(addon1 == 0)
            printf("16 GB memory:        \t 0.00\n");
        if(addon1 == 1)
            printf("32 GB Memory:       \t 389.00\n");
        if(addon2 == 0)
            printf("32 inch LED monitor:\t 0.00\n");
        if(addon2 == 1)
            printf("28 inch 4K HD monitor:\t 299.00\n");
        if(addon3 == 0)
            printf("256 GB SSD Drive:  \t 0.00\n");
        if(addon3 == 1)
            printf("512 GB SSD:         \t 299.00\n");
        if(addon3 == 2)
            printf("1TB SSD:         \t 599.00\n");
        if(addon4 = 0)
            printf("2 GB Discrete Video Card: \t 0.00");
        if(addon4 = 1)
            printf("4 GB Discrete Video Card: \t 399.00");

        printf("================================\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a homework assignment?

Comment: no! just practising programming using online tutorials!

Answer (score 0):

You should use boolean array of addOn rather then declaring 3 different variable. And to make any modification use functions.

1) Like buy() 
2) Modify() 
3) Print()

Use sum variable, that will calculate the total cost. And whenever bill is to be modified just send sum to Modify() as argument and add or decrease from the sum.

This is simple approach try it. And make sure to keep a check so that customer can't use Modify() without buying something!

Answer (score 0):

First thing, use array to store addon. And use (user input - 1) as array index;

You are not adding prices. In each if statement that check for user input, add prices as well.

```
price = 0
if(addon1 == 1)
{
        printf("8 GB Memory:        \t 99.00\n");
        price += 99.00;
}
else if(addon1 == 2)
{
        printf("12 GB Memory:       \t 189\n");
        price += 189.00
}
```

..................
And so on.